# Micro:Bit and Python Serial Connection Missing Characters

Tags: serial-port, pyserial, bbc-microbit

I am running a Python program in a VSCode window and a micro:bit, with a make code program running. The micro:bit is sending information to the python window through a serial connection on baud rate 115200. The issue is that whenever the Python program prints what is coming from the serial monitor, it is missing certain characters. Take a look at this sample data

1000
1000
1000
100
1000
100
000
1000

It should all be '1000' but some are distorted.

Here is the Python program

```
import serial
import time


ser = serial.Serial()
counter = 0

# Set the serial port and baud rate
ser.port = '/dev/tty.usbmodem14102'
ser.baudrate = 115200

try:
    # Open the serial port
    print('Opening')
    ser.open()
    print(f'Serial port {ser.port} opened successfully')
except serial.SerialException as e:
    print(f'Error opening serial port {ser.port}: {e}')
    exit(1)


while True:
    if not paused:
        data = ser.readline().decode().strip()
        print(data)
    else:
        print('Nothing Coming this way....')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

And this is the micro:bit code, running in Microsoft Makcode: JavaScript

```
let p8 = 0
let p7 = 0
let p6 = 0
let p5 = 0
serial.redirect(SerialPin.USB_TX, SerialPin.USB_RX, BaudRate.BaudRate115200)
led.enable(false)
basic.forever(function on_forever() {
    
    p5 = pins.digitalReadPin(DigitalPin.P5)
    p6 = pins.digitalReadPin(DigitalPin.P6)
    p7 = pins.digitalReadPin(DigitalPin.P7)
    p8 = 0
    serial.writeLine("" + p5 + ("" + p6) + ("" + p7) + ("" + p8))
    basic.pause(1000)
    basic.pause(1000)
})
```

Whenever I tried running this setup on OS X 12.6.3, some of the bytes were missing.

Thank you